# Can Asgardian Gods die?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

In Avengers, Loki drops Thor from a ship 30k feet above the ground and says:

> The humans think us immortal. Should we test that?

In Thor: Ragnarok,

- > Odin died (or dissolved?)
- > Hela was surprised to see Thor and Loki alive
- > Hela dies at the end (apparently)

So, can Asgardian Gods die in the MCU or are they really immortal? What can kill them?

Comment: Are you Frigga kidding me?

Comment: Who do you think populates Valhalla and Hel?

Comment: And in The Dark World Odin says "We are not Gods. We are born, we live, we day. Just as humans do." And Loki replies "Give or take 5,000 years".
So it would seem they even have a life span.

Comment: And the Hulk flips Loki and Thor around like a rag doll, yet Thanos can squeeze Loki's neck to kill him. Hela stabbed Thor several dozen times, without killing him, but only stabbed the other Asgard people once to kill them. So inconsistent!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ....can Asgardian Gods die in the MCU?

## Yes

Frigga died in *Thor: A Dark World* from being *stabbed* and she was the wife of Odin.

What their death actually *entails* has not been clarified although it seems to involve transcendence to another plane of existence (perhaps Valhalla, Hel or possibly Fólkvangr.)

Note. **Immortal** does not mean *unkillable*...at least for the Asgardians in the MCU. It just means **very long-lived**.

> Immortality: They usually don't age, but can be killed - although more than likely it will be incredibly difficult and takes a great deal of effort or special item to do so. Sometimes only a god can kill another god. And it's not uncommon for them to be resurrected, either - although they may lose their memories or be forced to take a new form.
>
> <sup>[TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PhysicalGod)</sup>